# Why javascripts referenced in JSLink are cached by browser (max-age=31536000)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink

## Context

Recently, I noticed that browsers cache the javascript files that have been referenced from the JSLink property of a OOB list form.

Analyzing the network traffic with chrome dev tools, I can see the cause for this. These javascripts have in http response header the following setting:

```
Cache-Control:private,max-age=31536000
```

## Notes

- This problem is not related to MDS feature. I see the same behavior with either MDS enabled or disabled
- I'm storing js files in the SiteAssets library of the OOB team site

## Question

I've found different workarounds to solve this problem, but I really would like to know:

- do you know the **WHY** of such a behavior?
- did you ever experience such a problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply it's to reduce traffic. If the file haven't changed, why not just use the cached version?

I have experienced this plenty of times and my workaround is always the same:

If I want to make sure the file is **always** reloaded I add a timestamp or auto-generated `guid` at the end of the file reference to ensure the cache is updated everytime.

Comment: Yes that's obvious. But do you know why it does this only for JSLinked files, I don't have output cache configured too? javascript files linked from web pages have max-age=0, while those JSLinked are always cached.

Comment: @EmilianoPoggi Because JSLinked files are used in correlation to lists, views, and the like, which needs to load fast and the OOTB SP files rarely/never changes.

Comment: Don't worry ... IF may 4th webinar they show us the new (First Release) Library View IS the new SharePoint way.... then you won't have any CSR

Comment: Thanks @DanielZiga so it seems a standard behavior we have to live with :(

Comment: @DannyEngelman can you be more precise about this webinar? do you have any link? Thank you